# Avalonia UI, background obscures what I drew at Render

Tags: avaloniaui

I created a custom control by inheriting `UserControl` and drew a rectangle at `Render`

```
    public override void Render(DrawingContext context)
    {
        base.Render(context);
        context.DrawRectangle(ThePen, TheBox);
    }
```

The box was displayed but when I set `Background` in the XAML of the MainWindow, the background colour obscured the box (box was not visible). Can I make the the box shown on top of the background colour?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from UserControl? Custom-drawn controls should inherit from Control directly.

Comment: @kekekeks I changed it to `Control` but there then there was no `Background` property. Do I have to implement all the background-related stuff myself?